# AWX-Web error when installing awx-operator on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-awx

I am currently installing the awx-operator and I have come across an issue while I am trying to expose the application to the outside world.

But I have come across an error with the `awx-web` container within the `awx-5b58db49c-9r4hp`. When I run `kubectl logs pod/awx-5b58db49c-9r4hp -c awx-web`, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/awx/conf/settings.py", line 81, in _ctit_db_wrapper
    yield
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/awx/conf/settings.py", line 411, in __getattr__
    value = self._get_local(name)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/awx/conf/settings.py", line 355, in _get_local
    setting = Setting.objects.filter(key=name, user__isnull=True).order_by('pk').first()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 653, in first
    for obj in (self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1]:
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1140, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "awx"

2021-05-12 14:28:54,478 ERROR    [-] awx.conf.settings Database settings are not available, using defaults.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2_provider/settings.py", line 138, in __getattr__
    val = self.user_settings[attr]
KeyError: 'OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "awx"
```

I am not too sure whether this is a big deal or just a red-herring. I am just in need of some clarification. If I need to get any more information to aide troubleshooting, please let me know!

Comment: No the password doesn't contain any of those characters

Comment: what env you use? check [AWX 19.0.0: password authentication failed for user "awx"](https://groups.google.com/g/awx-project/c/wC9ZD2-uA30).  2 days ago update states: "The problem doesn't occur anymore with minikube v1.20.0, awx-operator 0.9.0."

Answer (score 1):

As per [AWX 19.0.0: password authentication failed for user "awx"](https://groups.google.com/g/awx-project/c/wC9ZD2-uA30) issue is not anymore in `minikube v1.20.0, awx-operator 0.9.0` so advice is try use this version for now

Answer (score 0):

I was also observing the same error message => password authentication failed for user "awx".

I was running the awx-operator version 0.10.0 on my kubernetes cluster created using kubeadm and not using minikube.
I hosted my postgres persistent volume needed for awx postgres pod on my worker node which already had some stale previously migrated data from a different kubernetes cluster. I had to cleanup that already lying data on my worker node hostPath where i mounted my persistent volume and make a fresh install with fresh data from postgres pod and the password authentication error never come back.